# Why am I stuck at 640x480 on an Optimus hybrid-graphics system?

Tags: nvidia, screen, resolution

I have Intel HD 3000 graphics card onboard and nvidia 520 mx optimus techolonogy card. I was try to install Nvidia driver but it was failure. Now I cant use anything. Have one resolution 640x480
every media disconnected and I cant connect

> $ xrandr Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 640 x 480, maximum 8192
>   x 8192 LVDS1 connected 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis
>   y axis) 344mm x 194mm    640x480        59.9*  VGA1 disconnected
>   (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI1 disconnected (normal
>   left inverted right x axis y axis) DP1 disconnected (normal left
>   inverted right x axis y axis)
>
> lspci | grep VGA 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation
>   2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
>   (rev 09

)

> glxinfo | grep vendor server glx vendor string: SGI client glx vendor
>   string: Mesa Project and SGI OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics,
>   Inc
>   Blockquote something wrong here I guess
>   I try to some solutions but didnt work even it cant nvidia-xconfig file after these
>   By the way system get eror sometimes about xorg 
>   Sorry for my English 
>   thaks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Comment: try to install bumblebee: http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html

Comment: OP, did you get this fixed yet? If yes, you should post your solution to help others.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem a couple of days ago every time I tried to install that driver.

Go to the terminal, and run
`$ sudo nvidia-xconfig

$ sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
Look for

> HorizSync 28.0 - 33.0
>   VertRefresh 43.0 - 72.0

Replace with

> HorizSync 30.0 - 83.0
>   VertRefresh 56.0 - 75.0

Save. Reboot. Go to System Settings >> Displays and select the correct resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. This really helped solved my problem of screen being stuck at 640 x 480. These two lines did the Job:

```
HorizSync 30.0 - 83.0
VertRefresh 56.0 - 75.0
```

Instead of

```
HorizSync 28.0 - 33.0
VertRefresh 43.0 - 72.0
```

I got in these problems while trying to set Compiz effects and installing nVidia then I got this message when trying to launch nVidia Settings.

Also I got this nasty Message:

```
Could not apply the stored configurations for monitors
```

None of the selected modes were compatible with the possible modes:

```
Trying modes for CRTC 297
.
.
.
.
.

Followed by a long list...   CRTC 297: trying mode 1366x768@50Hz with output at 3286x1080@51Hz (pass 0)
```

When accessing nVidia:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X
configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
```